# DefaultProps for React StatelessComponent in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript1.8, typescript-typings

I wanted to use react stateless component in typescript with defaultProps.

I am not able to find solution how to use typings that would allow me to use **defaultProps** in **TypeScript** project without diamond syntax.

```
import {Link} from "react-router";

interface LinkProps {
    ...
}

const LinkPresenter = (props: LinkProps): JSX.Element =>
    <Link
        ...
    >
        ...
    </Link>;

LinkPresenter.defaultProps = { // !!! unresolved variable defaultProps
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for link I was not able to find anything helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type **React.SFC** allow to attach **defaultProps** to react stateless component.

Bellow you can find simplified example of **React.SFC** with **defaultProps**.

```
import {Link} from "react-router";

interface LinkProps {
    to?: HistoryModule.LocationDescriptorObject;
    onClick?: (event: React.FormEvent) => void;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

const LinkPresenter: React.SFC = (props: LinkProps): JSX.Element =>
    <Link
        className="link"
        to={props.to}
        onClick={props.onClick}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Link>;

// Alternative syntax
const LinkPresenter: React.StatelessComponent = (props: LinkProps): JSX.Element =>
...

LinkPresenter.defaultProps = { // now we can use defaultProps
    to: {
        pathname: `/homepage`,
        query: {
            default: 'someDefault'
        }
    },
    onClick: () => {},
    children: <span>Hello world</span>,
};
```

Comment: but you don't need to do this with typescript, you can set the default props in the method signature i.e const LinkPresenter: React.SFC = (props: LinkProps = {to: {pathname:'',query}}): JSX.Element

Comment: @RossScott that's an interesting idea, although I guess it only lets you specify the whole props object, rather than specific default properties.

Comment: @RossScott: I am new to typescript I like the syntax your suggested.

Comment: You can have multiple properties passed in, each with their own default value. You can also define the default value outside of the function as a variable and then assign that.

Comment: this does not seem to work for me: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ufek81

Comment: to anyone wondering this is a bug in Typescript 3.1, should be fixed when 3.2 comes out

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on our conversation, here is an alternative using the TS / ES6 default property approach:

```
import {Link} from "react-router";

interface LinkProps {
    to?: HistoryModule.LocationDescriptorObject;
    onClick?: (event: React.FormEvent) => void;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

let defaultProps : LinkProps = {
  to: {
        pathname: `/homepage`,
        query: {
            default: 'someDefault'
        }
  },
  onClick: () => {},
  children: <span>Hello world</span>
}

const LinkPresenter = (props: LinkProps = defaultProps): JSX.Element =>
    <Link
        className="link"
        to={props.to}
        onClick={props.onClick}
    >
        {props.children}
    </Link>;
```

Comment: Your solution works differently with nested objects, and keys with undefined values.

Comment: This syntax if called with undefined as props will return undefined props. The defaultProps approach will work attach default props.

Comment: How would this work if you destructured the component props?